# How to invalidate bearer token at server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, authorization, owin, bearer-token

I save all of the generated bearer tokens into a database at sign-in time. Now I want to check if the request bearer does not exists in database, reject it. Where should I put it?

Note that I want this to happen in the Owin pipeline. (**Not** in the webapi pipeline. For example inside the `[Authorize]` attribute)

Comment: "I save all of the generated bearer tokens into a database at sign-in time" you should not do it. That's like keeping passwords in plain text

Comment: Yes you are right and I didn't do that at the end. As I explained in the answer I have just added some server keys to the token which will be checked at the token deciphering phase

Comment: how do you get access to raw generated bearer tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inherit from `OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider` like this :

```
public class ApplicationOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{    

    public override Task ValidateIdentity(OAuthValidateIdentityContext context)
    {            
        var result=  base.ValidateIdentity(context);

        if (context.IsValidated )
        {
            var ticket = context.Ticket;

            if (ticket != null && ticket.Identity.IsAuthenticated && ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc > DateTime.UtcNow)
            {
                if (1==2)//TODO: put your server side condition here
                {
                    context.SetError("HaHa!");
                }
            }

        }

        return result;

    }

}
```

and use it in your `startup.cs` class like this :

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider(),             
        });  
    }
}
```